# What is the name of the group that contains both lines and shapes?

Tags: geometry

I'm sorry if this question doesn't belong here, but I have a dilemma.
I need the name of the group that contains both lines and shapes, since a line is not a shape, and a shape is not a line.

I don't know if there is one, but if there is, i'd like to know the name, you see I'm developing a graphics app were you can animate properties of lines and shapes (without the need of a differentiation), so, i need a name that could group them both.

Thanks, I hope you understand the question :)

Comment: Not everything in mathematics has its own name. Why don’t you just call them objects?

Comment: You should be aware that "group" has a strict mathematical definition that is different than what you are talking about. Many people will read the title of your question and be very confused.

Comment: Because I don't like generic names like objects (given that in programming "object" is a very used name and it has it's own meaning).

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "the group" and by "shape"? Would the word "figure" be relevant?

Comment: Thank you anon! http://www.mathwords.com/g/geometric_figure.htm Yes, a figure contains both shapes and lines as it's: "any set of points on a plane or in space". Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broadest term that seems to make sense to me is *curve*. A Euclidean line is, you could say, a "straight curve."

A curve that stops where it starts (called a *closed curve*) can form a shape like a circle, or something more complicated with loops. Used this way, the name doesn't imply anything about being smooth: you can have sharp corners and line segments.

If you feel uncomfortable calling straight lines and polygons "curves," then geometry books have an analogue called *broken lines*, meaning figures that are line segments placed end to end. You can reason that a single line segment is just a very simple broken line, and that a polygon (like a rectangle or pentagon) is a broken line that stops where it started.

If you don't like these, then something generic like "figure" or "diagram" might cover your cases.

Comment: Thank you, this is very insightful, but for the purpose of simplicity, I will use the name figure, thank you very much for taking your time :)